# How to remove light fixture

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I'm having trouble getting this light fixture off the wall (*I need to look in there to see if I can spot any loose wiring, the light turns on and off when we wiggle the fixture!*).

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get it apart, mainly because it's so tight to the ceiling.

Does anyone know how it's done?

[image: the light fixture viewed from below]

[image: detail of fixture]

Comment: "*the light turns on and off when we wiggle the fixture!*" Reminds me of the joke. **Patient**; "it hurts when i pull my finger". **Doctor**; "Dont pull your finger."  Don't wiggle the fixture.

Comment: Hahaha, great reference... sadly, I was being a little reductive... it turns on and off when the fixture is wiggled, _but it also turns on and off at random_! Seems like the house is wiggling enough to wiggle the fixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One** of the three clips will be spring loaded.

Pull straight out on it, while supporting the glass, and then the glass will be able to swing down and out of the other two.

Once the glass is removed you can access the fasteners, two screws or nuts, that are holding the fixture to the box in the ceiling.

**Turn the breaker off** that is supplying power to the light **before** you do anything with the wiring.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just tried this, on all three of the clips, pulling away from the center, parallel to the ceiling. No success so far. I do note though, of the three clips, the one pictured looks a bit different to the other two, which is just like you suggested - the other two are flush to the cylinder, while the pictured one can move a bit relative to the cylinder. Do you think I'm just not pulling hard enough?

Comment: The force is strong with this one. Yes pull and wiggle it a little as you pull. I wish i had nickle for - - - -.

Comment: I just did my greatest _the hulk_ impression, and still, no movement from any of the three. :(

Comment: The answer is good. I just checked a similar light now, and looking from the side the "special" clip has a bolt thread visible from the side. The other two do  not.

Comment: yeah, I agree... there's nothing else that could possibly be right. Shame that mine seems super-super stuck... If you think of anything that might unstick it, let me know! :)